# Simple linked list with two iterators

Tags: c#, linked-list, iterator

As part of the practice, I created minimalist linked list named `SimpleList` which can be iterated in two different ways: one element after another or by every second element.

Because I'm beginner I would really appreciate your opinion about my solution. Is it correct? What should I change?

```
public class SimpleList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    protected class Node
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public Node NextNode { get; set; }

        public Node(T data, Node nextNode)
        {
            Data = data;
            NextNode = nextNode;
        }
    }

    protected Node Head { get; set; } = null;

    public void Add(T data)
    {
        Head = new Node(data, Head);
    }

    #region IEnumerable<T> implementation
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var current = Head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Data;
            current = current.NextNode;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion

    #region second iterator implementation
    private class EverySecondElementIterator : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private readonly Node head;

        public EverySecondElementIterator(Node head)
        {
            this.head = head;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var current = head;
            while (current != null)
            {
                yield return current.Data;
                current = current.NextNode?.NextNode;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> EverySecondElement => new EverySecondElementIterator(Head);
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Use extension methods

I find you did well by implementing the `EverySecondElementIterator` as a separate class. However, I also think it would be better to turn it into an extension of `IEnumerable<T>` and use `MoveNext` instead of the internal `Node`.

Otherwise if someone suddenly comes up with the idea to skip every third element, you would need to modify the original `SimpleList` by creating another private class class and another property. We usually try to avoid modifying code that is tested and is working well. This would also violate the [open/closed principle](http://joelabrahamsson.com/a-simple-example-of-the-openclosed-principle/).

It's much safer and extendable to create a new and independent extension that you also can resue with any `IEnumerable<T>` and skip every-second-element of any collection.

Let the `SimpleList` be closed for modifications by not implementing anything as specific as that enumerator. It is already opend for extension by implementing the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. Make use of it.

Comment: You mean something like this: [SimpleList.cs](https://pastebin.com/d3jMbhCc), [IEnumerableExtensions.cs](https://pastebin.com/fmSs9rb6), [Program.cs](https://pastebin.com/aDyVWyxV)?

My concerns: 1. extension class name starts with capital I but it's not an interface (what's proper naming convention?). 2. Static class can't be generic so my enumerator returns plain objects. Is it ok?

Comment: @techb0t Or should I cast it to desirable type?

Comment: @wozar since you know the `T`, it'd easier be easier when you implemented the generic interface `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: I'm sorry but where should I implement it?

Comment: I mean if I implement generic IEnumerable in my private `EverySecondElementIterator` class I still can't return it without casting to non-generic since static class doesn't know about T

Comment: Or I simply don't know how

Comment: @wozar I think you know how to do it because you've already been there, this is what you have shown us in your question: `EverySecondElementIterator : IEnumerable<T>`, all you have to do is to exchange `Node` against `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @wozar what I see here is the simple interface `EverySecondElementIterator : IEnumerable`

Comment: Oh, I got confused because I forgot to add <T> to method name which returns new EverySecondElementIterator<T>. My bad.

Comment: So it works great now. Thank you very much for your help. I really like this approach. Using extension methods makes it easy to extend so I guess it's preferred way to implement many iterators for some type. Am I correct? Or are there any exceptions or restrictions?

Comment: @wozar I'm glad you could solve this _riddle_ ;-) The questions you are asking would be perfect for a follow-up question because there's still room for improvement. In case you are tempted to do so.. please do not modify the code here. A new qeustion would be the right thing to do to ask for feedback about the new code.

Answer (score 5):

### Terminology

The `Add` operation on a `List` appends the *item* to that *list*. Your method should be renamed to `Prepend`.

> ```
>  public void Add(T data)
>  {
>       Head = new Node(data, Head);
>  }
> ```

```
 public void Prepend(T data)
 {
      Head = new Node(data, Head);
 }
```

### Design

You could keep track of the `Tail` and have an `Add` operation.

> `protected Node Head { get; set; } = null;`

```
 protected Node Head { get; set; } = null;
 protected Node Tail { get { 
     var tail = Head;
     while (tail != null && tail.NextNode != null)
         tail = tail.NextNode;
     return tail;
 }}

 public void Add(T data)
 {
     if (Head == null)
         Head = new Node(data, null);
     else
         Tail.NextNode = new Node(data, null);
 }
```

Comment: Nothing more? I'm worried about this you can alternate list while iterating over it. What if we have two iterators? Should I prevent this e.g. using readonly copies od list? How can I even make such copy? It doesn't use any built in collection so it won't be trivial...

Comment: @wozar It's up to caller code to know how to iterate over IEnumerable instances and how to allow/restrict concurrent access.

Comment: Thank you for naming suggestion. I also noticed that you don't keep tail as simple reference to last added element and I have concerns about performance. Is it necessary if we can manipulate list only with this class' public methods? If I'm correct we can't modify node's `NextNode` property from outside `SimpleList` class so it should be impossible to break this list by adding next node before tail and creating some sort of branching.

Comment: @wozar It's a design decision whether you want to keep track of other properties other than head that could also get calculated on demand. If performance is key, I would store the tail as well. If memory storage should be kept low, I would not.